# Error in CREATE TYPE statement in DB2 for z/OS

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos, sqlcode

i tried create an associative array with integer indexes

```
CREATE TYPE assocArray AS VARCHAR(1000) ARRAY[INTEGER];
```

And DB2 returns me this:

> ILLEGAL SYMBOL 'ARRAY'. SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: CHECK UNIQUE NOT PRIMARY AS UPDATE IMPLICITY INLINE CONSTRAINT. SQLCODE = -104, SQLSTATE = 42601, DRIVER = 3.68.61

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: What is the *version* of the Db2 for Z that you are using ?

Comment: ARRAY support for Db2/Z  arrived in Version 11.  If you are using V10 or lower than you are out of luck until you upgrade.

Comment: My DB2 version is 11.1

Comment: And is the Db2 11 in New Function Mode (NFM) ?

Comment: when i tried query this i got this: DSN10015

Comment: DSN10015 identifies DB2 10 in new-function mode.

Answer (score 1):

If your Db2 for Z/OS is V10 or lower then ARRAY is not implemented. Your Db2-server for Z/OS needs to be V11 New Function Mode or higher if you want define  ARRAYs.